# Direct domain name to index.php in .htaccess without specifying domain name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to direct a domain name like http://www.domain.com or http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com/index.php using .htaccess. However, I don't want to specify the actual domain name in the .htaccess file to make the file generic and to work with all domain names. So in the example below, I don't want to specify domain.com.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just tell Apache to use `index.php` as its default file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be generic, don't put a condition on host.

All you have to do is this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

This matches *root* url. If matched then redirect to `index.php`